# Hidden Padding/Margin Making Sidebar Content Smaller

Tags: html, css, wordpress, widget, sidebar

First time posting,

This should be simple but I cannot seem to find the cause for it. Some of my sidebar widgets stretch to full 300 width, but both the Facebook and WordPress Popular Posts widgets change.

The Facebook widget width is lowered to 240px, while the WordPress Popular Posts widget is pushed to the right by 60px. It seems there is some invisible padding/margin, but I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

I couldn't add images due to first time posting. My website name is www.gosu-tech.com and the widgets are located on the right of any single post. Any help would be great, I can add the changes on the back-end and see if it makes any difference.

Thanks,

Comment: I think its floated to right.

Comment: check for margin in child elements... sometimes child element margin becomes part of parent but is not clearly shown by inspect element.... it's called [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to customize your css.

Remove padding-left of WordPress Popular Posts widget so that the two widgets are vertically aligned:

```
.wpp-list {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Regarding the width, it seems that it comes from this css class:

```
.col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Try to set the width to 30%.